# How find this $x,y$ such this equation $x^x+x=y!$

Tags: number-theory

> Find all pairs of positive integers $(x,y)$,such
>   $$x^x+x=y!$$

I find the $$(x,y)=(1,2)$$ is such it. and 
$$(x,y)=(2,3)$$

I think this equation have other roots. and maybe use inequality to solve this?
since Use  Bernoulli inequality we  have 
$$x^x=(x-1+1)^x\ge 1+x(x-1)=x^2-x+1$$

Thank you for you help, this problem is from Mathematical contest in china jiangxi province in 2014

Comment: How about $(x,y)=(n,n^n+n)$ for any integer $n$?

Comment: @user134824, $n^n+n \neq (n^n+n)!$ for any integer.

Comment: I read your factorial as punctuation! Oops.

Answer (score 18):

$y\le 1$ leads to no solution.
For $y>1$ we have $y!=\prod_{k=1}^y k<\prod_{k=1}^y y=y^y$.
Hence $y!=x^x+x$ implies $y^y>x^x$ and thus $y>x$ (the function $f(t)=t^t$ is obviously strictly increasing because $(t+1)^{t+1}>(t+1)^t>t^t$).
As you have already found the solution $x=1, y=2$, we may assume that $x>1$.
Let $p$ be a prime divisor of $x$. Then $x^{x-1}+1$ is not a multiple of $p$, hence neither is $\frac{y!}{x}$. That is, if we strike $x$ from the list $1, 2,\ldots, \not x,\ldots , y$, none of the remaining numbers is a multiple of $p$.
This leaves only the possibility that $x=p$ as otherwise $p$ remains on the list.
Thus $x$ is prime.
We already know the solution $x=2$, $y=3$, hence may assume that $x$ is an odd prime.
Then $x^{x-1}+1\equiv 2\pmod 4$, hence $\frac {y!}x$ is not a multiple of $4$. This implies $y<4$ and you have already found all solutions with $y<4$ by exaustive search.

Comment: Hello, I don't understand this : if we strike $x$ from the list $1,2,\cdots,x,\cdots,y$,? before you have $y>x$?But why $x$ can $1,2,\cdots,y$? Thank you

Comment: @math110 To put it differently, if $x$ is composite, i.e. $x=pr$ with $p$ prime and $r>1$, then from $p<x<y$ we see that both $p$ and $x$ are among the factors in the *definition* of $y!$. In other words, $\frac{y!}{px}$ is an integer (namely a product of some fewer factors). But $\frac{x^x+x}{px}=\frac{x^{x-1}+1}{p}$ is not an integer because the numerator is $\equiv 1\pmod p$.

Comment: Oh,Thank you.I Understand.and @benh methods is simple?

Answer (score 17):

It's easy to prove that if $x>3$ then $x<y,$ thus $x-1\mid y!,$ but $x^x+x\equiv 1^x+1\equiv 2\pmod{x-1},$ a contradiction.

Comment: The other answers are merely good. This two-liner is special!

Answer (score 7):

If $x>2$ is even, then $(x^{x-1}+1)x=y!$ shows that any power of $2$ dividing $y!$ divides $x$. Therefore $$x\geq 2^{\lfloor y/2 \rfloor}.$$ For $x>2$ this implies $x>y$, a contradiction because $x^x+x>x!$.

If $x>1$ is odd and $x^x+x=y!$, then $y\geq 4$. Therefore $4 \mid y! = x^x+x$ and $$x^{x-1}\equiv -1 \bmod 4.$$
This implies that $-1$ is a quadratic residue $\bmod\, 4$, a contradiction.

Comment: Incorrect statement. $4 \not | 3^3+3$

Comment: @EhsanM.Kermani Well, because there is no solution to $x=3$. The reasoning for $4 \mid x^x=x$ is that $x^x+x=y!$ and $4\leq y$.

Answer (score 2):

There are no other such pair of integers for $x>2$.

**Updated Proof:**

1. If $x$ is not prime:

   - $x^x \geq x! \implies x^x+x>x!$
   - Therefore, we must choose $y>x$
   - $x^x+x$ is divisible by $x$ exactly once, because $\frac{x^x+x}{x}=x^{x-1}+1$ is not divisible by $x$
   - But since $x$ is not prime, for every $y>x$ that we choose, $y!$ is divisible by $x$ at least twice
2. If $x$ is a prime such that $x \equiv 1 \bmod 6$, then let's analyze $x^{x-1}+1$:

   - $x^K \equiv 1 \bmod 6$ for every non-negative integer $K$
   - $x^{x-1} \equiv 1 \bmod 6$, since $x-1$ is a non-negative integer
   - $x^{x-1}+1 \equiv 2 \bmod 6$
   - $x^{x-1}+1$ is not divisible by $3$
   - $x^x+x$ is not divisible by $3$, hence, no $y>2$ exists such that $x^x+x=y!$
3. If $x$ is a prime such that $x \equiv 5 \bmod 6$, then let's analyze $x^{x-1}+1$:

   - $x^K \equiv 1 \bmod 6$ for every non-negative **even** integer $K$
   - $x^{x-1} \equiv 1 \bmod 6$, since $x-1$ is a non-negative **even** integer
   - $x^{x-1}+1 \equiv 2 \bmod 6$
   - $x^{x-1}+1$ is not divisible by $3$
   - $x^x+x$ is not divisible by $3$, hence, no $y>2$ exists such that $x^x+x=y!$
4. Finally, if $x=3$ then $x^x+x=30$, and no $y$ exists such that $y!=30$

Comment: Wait! the first statement is incorrect. odd + odd =even!

Comment: @Ehsan M. Kermani: Yeah, I know, I removed it straight away (before your comment was made visible).

Comment: Even in your even/odd case, it's not obvious why $m>n?$ you only know that $y>m$ and $y>n$ not necessarily $m>n.$

Comment: @Ehsan M. Kermani: Thanks. I updated the proof from `even/odd` to `prime/not-prime`.